# How to create index for mongodb dynamically added collections?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is there any way to configure the db that auto create_index() when a new collections created?
Or do we have some best practice?

I have many collections storing docs with the same schema. different collections means different tenant, and collections are created dynamically.

Comment: How are you creating the new collections?

Answer (score 1):

**Copy index** after collections are created.

```
var indexKeys = db.collection1.getIndexKeys();
db.collection2.createIndexes(indexKeys);
```